# would it be easy to wrap spring mvc with a scala functional style?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, scala

I like spring mvc's functionality, but i'd like to not use annotations and use a more functional style... something with currying and closures rather than method names and annotations. Would this be easily doable?

Answer (score 1):

"something with currying and closures" is a little bit vague here :)

What you're asking is equivalent to "I like cars, but I'd like to not use petrol and find a more ecological style, can I do something with metallic paint and central locking rather than valves and pistons?"

Scala works well with Spring, and I'm successfully using them together with spring's fully annotation-driven controllers.  Annotations are the language that Spring speaks, so you can't really get away from them (unless you use XML configuration).

You CAN use a more functional approach if you handle dependency injection natively within Scala, and if you migrate to something like the Lift framework.  But then you're not using spring any more.

Which is not such a great loss :)